# How to delete lost files in NTFS drive

Tags: linux, windows, disk-space

I faced a problem like the one described [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/544365/external-hard-disk-not-able-to-read-some-folders-after-connecting-to-lg-led-tv/). Basically, after connecting my NTFS external hard drive to my TV, two folders were lost, appearing only as a 0KB file.

I have been able to recover the information with a recovery tool. My problem now is that the "lost" files are still in the hard drive (so I have two copies of them, one I can't access and the other one in its right location -the retrieved files). The lost files are taking up a lot of space, so I´d like to remove them but I don´t know how. My normal approach would be to copy the files to another hard drive, format the problematic one and then copy the information to it again. However, I don´t have enough space in my other drives to do that.

Any tools or procedures to do that? I can use Windows and Linux tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem using [GetDataBackSimple](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm), after having no success with other tools like Recuva, ntfs-3g or Windows' chkdsk.

This tool will recover the files to a different unit, and place the found items in the originally-broken unit under a found.xxx directory, that can be deleted after the recovery.

Answer (score 1):

`chkdsk` tool will check filesystem for errors and attempt to fix them. The easiest way to start it is via Windows Explorer:

Open *Computer* and right-click corrupted hard disk, choose *Properties*.

[image: Right-click drive, click Properties]

Go to the *Tools* tab and click *Check now*.

[image: Tools tab, Check now button]

A window will appear, click *Start*.

[image: Start button]

Scanning and fixing problems may take some time (possibly even hours). Try to avoid using computer until it completes. Don't disconnect the drive and don't power off the system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I had already tried it before, and it does not complete successfully in Windows 7 (it does not raise any errors but it gets to a point in which instead of displaying a "xxx/yyyy registers checked" or something like that it just displays a huge number and never finishes). I'll try on Windows 8 later.

Comment: Try running it in the command line then, it may give us something more to work with. Press `Win` key to open Start menu, type `cmd` in the search box and press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. It should start Command Prompt as Administrator. Type `chkdsk /f E:` (substitute `E:` for drive letter) and press `Enter`, then note where it's stuck. (Actually it may be stuck for hours, then resume. Fixing filesystems is a hard job.)

Comment: I did try it on the terminal too. It finished successfully but the files are still taking the space up :/