# Wrong disk space displayed

Tags: windows-8.1, disk-space

My main SSD shows me that I have 2.51Gb space left.

[image]

But when I add up everything in C:/ by selecting all (including hidden folders and Windows folder) and looking at properties, it only takes 61.5Gb.

How in Windows' world 118Gb minus 61.5Gb can result in 2.51Gb? I ran CCleaner, Spybot, Avast, Windows cleaning disk tool, nothing changed.

[image]

Comment: Try a utility like WinDirStat to see what is using all the space. In 8.1, if you don't have ownership of a file, it will not be listed in that Folder Properties window.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/871274/why-do-i-have-300-gb-of-ghost-data-on-my-harddrive) ?

Comment: Seems to be close to this question indeed, but couldn't find any solution in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't aware of shadows, and it was the cause.

```
vssadmin list shadowstorage
```

Thanks to this command I found out I had 47Gb of backups. I just shrank the allowed shadow space to a few Gb, and I recovered all my disk space.