# “Program Files” File miraculously appeared on C: (win7)

Tags: windows-7

A file with no extension named "Program Files" appears in my c: drive. It acts as a mirror of the "Program Files" folder. I cannot delete it because it deletes the actual folder. How do i get rid of it as it's annoying to look at everytime i open the drive.

Heres a screenshot of the file in question.

[image]

[image: Get-Childitem C:\ -force]

Comment: How do you know that it acts as a mirror? What's inside the file? Can that be that file name is different using, for example 'o' char from other locale, or &nbsp instead of whitespace?

Comment: I guess 'mirror' isn't quite the word, but it's the best way i can explain it. The only difference is that the rename option comes up for the file, but trying to change it gives me a permission error on behalf of TrustedInstaller. I've also had this problem before and i messed with permissions in an attempt to get rid of the file, and when i could finally delete the file it automatically deleted the real folder, pretty sure i couldnt boot afterwards.

Comment: so that's a hypothesis, right? What about other answers?)

Comment: If i try to open it with notepad i get Access Denied just like the real folder, if i drag them into sublime text they both open folder navigation for "Program Files". If i open it with Internet Explorer it opens Program Files in the win7 Windows explorer. Not sure how i can read the file since it has no extension and acts as a folder..

Comment: Okay I JUST REALIZED that thers a space at the end of "Program Files " WHAT now!?

Comment: You can use something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlocker to see the process locking the file, then unlock, and check what's inside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22259/discussion-between-loaft-and-mikalai).

Answer (score 2):

Just to check if this could be symlink or hardlink, could you open cmd and enter the following commands please:

```
cd C:\
dir
```

Is the file flagged as symlink and/or are there square brackets with a path at the end like this?

```
18.03.2015  09:51    <SYMLINKD>     Program Files [C:\Program Files]
```

**Edit 1:**

Okay, please open Powershell as Administrator (search for Powershell, right click, run as Administrator), then try the following and let me know if it returns just a single entry:

```
cd C:\
Get-ChildItem C:\ | where{$_.mode -notlike "d*" -and $_.name -eq "Program Files"} | format-list
```

In the versioninfo line it should say File:

If that's worked try to rename the file:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ | where{$_.mode -notlike "d*" -and $_.name -eq "Program Files"} | Rename-Item -NewName "Program Files.old"
```

**Edit 2:**

So here's my C:\ folder:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> gci C:\ -Force


    Verzeichnis: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d--hs        27.06.2012     14:21            $Recycle.Bin
d--hs        15.02.2011     10:42            Boot
d----        28.11.2014     17:21            Chocolatey
d--hs        14.07.2009     07:08            Documents and Settings
d--hs        26.06.2012     17:22            Dokumente und Einstellungen
d-rh-        27.06.2012     10:28            MSOCache
d----        14.07.2009     05:20            PerfLogs
d-r--        28.11.2014     17:23            Program Files
d-r--        27.02.2015     08:38            Program Files (x86)
d--h-        16.11.2014     14:46            ProgramData
d--hs        26.06.2012     17:22            Programme
d--hs        14.10.2014     21:49            System Volume Information
d----        18.03.2015     09:51            temp
d-r--        29.06.2012     15:48            Users
d----        29.11.2014     19:54            Windows
d----        29.09.2014     18:00            xampp
-a---        25.11.2013     10:17       3072 ads_err.adi
-a---        06.09.2013     11:03       4562 ads_err.adm
-a---        25.11.2013     10:17      24843 ads_err.adt
-a---        19.04.2012     09:30        178 BOOT.TXT
-arhs        21.11.2010     04:23     383786 bootmgr
-arhs        15.02.2011     10:42       8192 BOOTSECT.BAK
-a---        12.08.2013     09:59         81 CTX.DAT
-a-hs        12.03.2015     08:48 3153510400 hiberfil.sys
-a---        23.09.2005     00:39     894976 msdia80.dll
-a-hs        12.03.2015     08:48 4204683264 pagefile.sys
```

My folder called Programme is called "Program Files" on English systems.

**Edit 3:**

Program Files is a Junction that Windows uses on NTFS. Opening one of the two Program Files folders should result in an access denied error.

```
C:\Windows\system32>dir /ah c:\
 Datenträger in Laufwerk C: ist Windows7_OS
 Volumeseriennummer: 04CF-2273

 Verzeichnis von c:\

27.06.2012  13:21    <DIR>          $Recycle.Bin
15.02.2011  10:42    <DIR>          Boot
21.11.2010  04:23           383.786 bootmgr
15.02.2011  10:42             8.192 BOOTSECT.BAK
14.07.2009  06:08    <JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
26.06.2012  16:22    <JUNCTION>     Dokumente und Einstellungen [C:\Users]
12.03.2015  08:48     3.153.510.400 hiberfil.sys
27.06.2012  09:28    <DIR>          MSOCache
12.03.2015  08:48     4.204.683.264 pagefile.sys
16.11.2014  14:46    <DIR>          ProgramData
26.06.2012  16:22    <JUNCTION>     Programme [C:\Program Files]
14.10.2014  20:49    <DIR>          System Volume Information
```

Comment: nothing as your example :
12/02/2015  09:58 PM            86,589 Program Files

http://i.imgur.com/lRKR0PG.png

Comment: Actually Windows doesn't let you create files that have the same name as a folder in the same location. I guess it's getting confused with the Program Files folder when you try to delete it. I'll add some steps to my answer.

Comment: I guess now its time to add in that this has happend once before and while trying to get rid of this cloned "file" i managed to fk up my entire os which i then had to format. Would the permissions of the file tell you anything?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem C:\ | where{$_.mode -notlike "d*" -and $_.name -eq "Program Files"} | format-list`
returns nothing, and get-childitem alone both "Program Files" look identical with mode d-r-- and writetime the same

Comment: Could you update your original question with the output of the following Powershell command: `Get-Childitem C:\ -force`

Comment: Ahh, I think I know what's going on. The folder you have issues with is a junction and Windows needs it to work. You should be able to list it with the following command in cmd.exe: dir /ah c:\ . You see it since you've chosen to show hidden files AND show system files in the Explorer options. You cannot remove it.

Comment: It's not a hidden file or system file, and it does not show up with "dir /ah c:".

Answer (score 0):

Creating a file and a folder with the same name shouldn't be possible. Judging by your comment on @megamorf's answer, this issue is caused by some buggy program that you're using.

Before trying to fix it, **ensure that your backups are up to date**. You're doing regular backups, right? :)

Then run filesystem check. If it goes well, it will delete that file. If it goes wrong, it may delete the real Program Files folder... so **make sure you have it backed up**.

Here's how to run this check: (from my [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/869260/194694))

> Open *Computer* and right-click corrupted hard disk, choose
>   *Properties*.
>
> [image: Right-click drive, click Properties]
>
> Go to the *Tools* tab and click *Check now*.
>
> [image: Tools tab, Check now button]
>
> A window will appear, click *Start*.
>
> [image: Start button]
>
> Scanning and fixing problems may take some time (possibly even hours).
>   Try to avoid using computer until it completes. Don't disconnect the
>   drive and don't power off the system.

Here we're talking about the C: drive which can't be checked on a running system, so Windows will ask you to reboot and will do its duties during boot.

If something goes wrong and the real Program Files folder is deleted, you'll have to restore it from backup (possibly using another PC because yours may fail to boot). Anyway you should be left with only one file/folder called Program Files which you'll be able to delete normally.

Comment: I will have to backup the folder althought nothing of value is in it and try your method. Will update if everything else fails.

Comment: Did the disk check, problem file is still relevant. Would appreciate any more input

Comment: On one of my computers, Check Disk took three to five days to run back when the disk had about 7,300,000 files, mostly due to the way Microsoft's email/news programs (Windows Mail and Windows Live Mail) used a separate file for each message in my VERY LARGE collection of newsgroups messages.  I've now mostly switched to Mozilla Thunderbird, which stores an entire folder of messages in each file.